# Javascript - Remove postfix from filename in url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a urls like this:

```
http://localhost/static/1941ce/917985481634941-350x_.png
http://localhost/static/1941ce/917985481634941-350x120.png
```

and I need to extract the original file name like this:

```
http://localhost/static/1941ce/917985481634941.png
```

What is a good way of doing this in Javascript?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use regex for this:

```js
var str1 = 'http://localhost/static/1941ce/917985481634941-350x_.png';
var str2 = 'http://localhost/static/1941ce/917985481634941-350x120.png';
var postfixRe = /-[0-9x_]*\./i;
console.log(str1.replace(postfixRe, '.'));
console.log(str2.replace(postfixRe, '.'));
```

If you are not sure that there will be only one occurence of '-':

```js
var str1 = 'http://localhost/static/1941ce/917985481634941-350x_.png';
var str2 = 'http://localhost/static/1941ce/917985481634941-350x120.png';
var postfixRe = /\/(\d+)-[0-9x_]*\./i;
console.log(str1.replace(postfixRe, '/$1.'));
console.log(str2.replace(postfixRe, '/$1.'));
```